# How to find where javascript starts and end in asp files?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, parsing, comments

I need to write a script in `c#` that recognizes javascript inside an ASP file.
I would like to start deleting all comments, but I am facing the problem: to know if a sequence of characters is a comment or not I need to know first if I am inside HTML or a script written in javascript.
Is there a (quite simple) way to recognize where the javascript code starts and ends?

Let's suppose I have this file, I need to remove the comment in javascript but not the same string in HTML, where it is not a comment:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
      try {
        if (top.location.href != location.href) {
          top.location.href = "myFile.aspx";
          //this is a comment
      } catch (e) { }
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>//this is not a comment</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it simple to check if you're inside a <script> </script> block?

Comment: Yeah, i hoped to find a better solution, but checking tag is the only way i've found till now